# 400 Bad Request with HTTParty and Urban Airship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty, urbanairship.com, http-status-code-400

I have an app that requires push notifications sent to user when a post matching certain criteria is put onto the db. I am using urban airship and HTTParty to make the necessary requests if the conditions are met. My model is as follows:

```
class Urbanairship
 include HTTParty
 base_uri 'https://go.urbanairship.com'
 headers "Content-Type" => "application/json"
 basic_auth "xxxappkeyxxx", "xxxappsecretxxx"
 default_params :output => 'json'
 format :json

 def self.push(badge, alert_message, token)
  self.post('/api/push/',:body => {:aps => {:badge => badge, :alert => alert_message},   :device_tokens => [token]})
 end
end
```

I keep getting a 400 bad request when I test this in the console. Any ideas as to what the problem is? I know that urban airship needs a 'content-type:application/json' in the request header, but that should be covered in the model. Thanks in advance,
Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know HTTParty myself, but the most if you can introspect the result and get the actual response body, that should tell you more. A 400 could be from the missing content-type, as you mentioned, or invalid JSON, but it could also be from a an invalid device token or badge number.

Comment: Yep. Turns out i forgot to add .to_json on the end of my body. And my auth was a little messed up. Introspect cleared all that up.